# 5Mill Users: how much hardware?

Tags: apache-2.2, hardware, load-balancing

I am working on a project and we expect about 5 Million Users per day.
It is a litte web application, written in php and we are currently using Apache to serve the requests.

My problem: I don't know how to calculate the hardware, I need to serve 5 Million Users a day. "Cloud" as in "go to Amazon" is not an option. But I thought about buying some big Servers and building our own Cloud with OpenStack or Eucalyptus.

How much Hardware do I need? Is virtualization an option?

Lastly: The webapp is mission critical - so I am going to double the hardware and do some failover - witch is a point for virtualization.

Comment: You will need to look at bringing some consultants on that know servers, virtualization, storage, etc. to help you get this setup.  You'll need to provide way to much information, which you probably don't want to provide in public anyway to get this moving.  These consultants won't be cheap.  If you find ones that are, they probably are the wrong ones.

Comment: Your question is not going to get a lot of serious responses, because it's pretty vague. What are the five million users doing? Do you use a database backend? Are you just serving static files? Without some more information of this sort, nobody is going to be able to give you a useful answer.

Comment: "we expect about 5 Million Users per day"..."a litte web application"...doesn't sound that little to me. Still, as the others have said, a conslutant is the best way to go.

Comment: Yes, I think I need a consultant. I thought there might be a "rule of thumb" to say "1M Users per Apache per day serving HTML, 500k Users per Apache per day serving php, 1M Users per day per mysqld" - just a very rough overview to see in which direction things are going. Thanks for your help, everyone!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Get help from consultants, we do not know the load of one instance on your server or what your webapplication does, is it memory greedy ? cpu greedy ?

You need a specialist that can look at your project and assemble a nice system, I wouldn't go for virtualisation if your instances can move through your cloud automatically, otherwise I'd look at the shadow option in Vmware ESX.

Get some professionals if you want to deploy something on this level, it's going to cost you, but a wrong answer on here might cost you even more on the long run.